# Issue to get height of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got some trouble to get the height of a div with jquery.

I create the div in the html and affect some text to it when I click a button. After that I want to get the height of that div to vertically align it in the parent div, But the `Height()` function of jquery return `0` to me.

In the debug console of google chrome I see the height of the div then I point at it, but the height is still not returning the value.

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FcJgz/415/)

Here is my result on JS FIDDLE

[image]

I got google chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: it returns height 180px for me...:?

Comment: I'm getting `180` in chrome!

Comment: That JSFiddle appears to work fine in Chrome. I am getting your height value (180).

Comment: @Prashank I got 0 on my screen ...

Comment: and its height() not Height()

Comment: @niko Yes I put height() in the fiddle

Comment: depend on the width of the screen ...I got 162 with a 1920x1080 resolution. The problem should that the element is not loaded in the DOM when you try to get the height.

Comment: @Hacketo It appear that I put the wrong fiddle ...

Comment: The fiddle works fine returns the correct value [not 0 ] on Chrome, Firefox, safari and IE... I am not sure what you are looking for?

Comment: @ClainDsilva I got 0 on chrome and IE ... can someone put a screenshot of the result ?

Comment: Sure here it is http://tinypic.com/r/303iqee/8

Comment: @ClainDsilva okay, that's the wrong fiddle ... I put the wrong link at first and edit it just before you try it ... Sorry :( But now if you try the link you would probably see my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the `div#lblMsgBoxMessage` is 0 because when you try to use :

```
$("#lblMsgBoxMessage").height()
```

the div element is **hided**.

You can try by clicking on the `div#click` again, and then the height is available because the element was already displayed.

You have to set the height **after** the :

```
$("#msgBox").show();
```

like this : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroc00l/rxP47/)

Answer (score 1):

Elements with `display: none` (including children of elements with `display: none`) have no height.  You need to show the element first in order to get its height.

If you move this line:

```
// display height of the message in the button
$("#click").text($("#lblMsgBoxMessage").height());
```

Underneath this line:

```
// display
$("#msgBox").show();
```

You'll be able to see the height.  JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FcJgz/416/